# Input array value in function reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to use "inputTime" in the if statement but i am not sure how to import it. I've tried "item.inputTime" and putting it in the "const check = (inputTime)" put i cant use it inside the check const. inputTime is an useState.

```
import React from 'react';
import nextId from "react-id-generator";

const Form = ({setInputText, inputText, setInputTime, inputTime, setInputDate, inputDate, todos, setTodos,  setStatus}) =>{

    

    const check = () => {
        var today = new Date();
        var curTime = today.getHours()+':'+today.getMinutes();

        todos.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.inputTime + curTime + inputTime);
            if(item.inputTime > curTime){
                console.log("if");
            } else{
                console.log("else");
            }
        });

    }

    return(
        <form>
            <input value={inputText} onChange={inputTextHandler} type="text" />

        

            <input value={inputTime} onChange={inputTimeHandler} type="time" />


            <button onClick={submitTodoHandler} type="submit">
                Lägg till
            </button>

            <button onClick={check(inputTime)} type="submit">
                Lägg till
            </button>
            <div>
                <select onChange={statusHandler}>
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                    <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reference of the function has to be passed to the onClick events.
In the line of code,

```
 <button onClick={check(inputTime)} type="submit"> Lägg till </button>
```

check(inputTime), triggers the function, instead of passing it as a reference. It has to be passed as a reference like,

```
onClick ={()=>check(inputTime)}
```

Here, a reference to an anonymous function is passed.
Please try it out.